# Removing a Point Object from a List: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to code a maze generator in python: maze is made up of a 2D List of integers: the List is meant to represent what this maze would look like in minecraft, so each cell actually lies where both the x and y coordinates are odd numbers.

The method i wrote to modify a cell's value within the "Maze" class keeps throwing the `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list` exception. Here is the code:

```
def setCell(self, x, y, request):
    query = Maze.blocks[(2*x)+1][(2*y)+1]
    if 0 <= x < (Maze.length-1)/2 and 0 <= y < (Maze.height-1)/2:
        if request > query:
            Maze.blocks[(2*x)+1][(2*y)+1] = request
            print('changed cell ' + str(x) + ', ' + str(y) + ' to ' + str(request))
            P = Point(x, y)
            if request == Maze.WORKING: #WORKING and DONE are constants
                Maze.List.append(P) 
                print(Maze.List) #debugging purposes
            elif request == Maze.DONE:
                print('trying to remove ' + str(P))

                Maze.List.remove(Point(P.x, P.y))
                #^^^here is the error.
                #I tried to use Maze.List.remove(P),
                #but that threw the exact same error.

                print(Maze.List)
            else:
                print('should NOT be writing ' + str(request) + ' to ' + str(query) + '!')
            return True
        else:
            print(str(request) + ' cannot overwrite ' + str(query))
            return False
    else:
        print('invalid range for cell. req was ' + str(x) + ', ' + str(y))
        return False
```

Here is when i run the code (i had the method print out what the maze looked like after it added each Point:

```
changed cell 2, 7 to 1
[Point(0, 8), Point(0, 7), Point(0, 9), Point(1, 9), Point(1, 7), Point(2,7)]
$ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ 
$ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * $ 
$ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ 
$ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * $ 
$ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ 
$ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * $ 
$ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ 
$ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * $ 
$ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ 
$ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * $ 
$ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ 
$ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * $ 
$ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ 
$ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * $ 
$ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ 
$ : : : : : @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * $ 
$ : $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ 
$ : @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * $ 
$ : $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ @ $ 
$ : : : @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * @ * $ 
$ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ 

changed cell 0, 7 to 2
trying to remove (0, 7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jim/PycharmProjects/MC_Maze/Maze.py", line 400, in <module>
    if not M.setCell(A.x, A.y, Maze.DONE):
  File "/Users/jim/PycharmProjects/MC_Maze/Maze.py", line 104, in setCell
    Maze.List.remove(Point(P.x, P.y))
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

You can see from the list that Point(0, 7) is on the list, but python doesn't seem to agree. As someone who is new to lower level languages like python, I have no clue why this won't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: python a lower level language??? that is new... other than that, my answer is the same as @AlexTaylor, also you can try `Maze.List.remove(P)`

Comment: I did try `Maze.List.remove(p)` but it had the same result. Im about to see what a unit test is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your `Point` class define [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) (for equality checks)? Putting the same values into a class does not automatically mean the class equals another one with the same values. The following shows what I think is going wrong with your code:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __init__(self, my_var):
...             self.my_var = my_var
...
>>> my_obj1 = MyClass("a value")
>>> my_obj2 = MyClass("a value")
>>> my_obj1 == my_obj2
False
```

Try writing a [unit test](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) for equality on your `Point` so you can check that it behaves the way you expect.

Comment: Woah! turns out just writing the method: `def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y` allowed `list.remove()` to work like a charm! thanks so much!

Comment: You should also define `__neq__`. This quote comes from the documentation I linked to for `__eq__`: "when defining __eq__(), one should also define __ne__() so that the operators will behave as expected."